# Allocating an Elastic IP address to an existing / running Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

Are we able to allocate an Elastic IP address to an existing / running Amazon EC2 instance?

In most cases, we assign the Elastic IP address before configuring the server. However, we are trying to assign the Elastic IP address onto a fully configured server and create an AMI for different instances.

If we associate the new EIP onto an existing instance (created by AMI) will run the same config as the existing one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elastic IPs can be allocated and associated to an EC2 instance at any time, while launching or after the launch.

An Elastic IP address is not actually the property of your instance, rather it's a property associated with your server's network card (Elastic Network Interface).

See: [Elastic IP Addresses - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-eips.html#vpc-eip-overview)

Comment: **Note:** When an Elastic IP is assigned to a running Amazon EC2 instance, it will lose any existing Public IP address. This means that any existing connections will need to be restarted (to the new IP address).

Comment: So is there any way to keep configuration + server IP config, while stopping the instance and re lunch via AMI?

Comment: Here's how you reserve a [private IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/config-windows-multiple-ip.html). For public IP reservation, use EIPs.